# Solidity: How to enter a value in a dynamic array inside a struct?

Tags: solidity, remix, struct

I'm working on the following code in Remix IDE. What I'm trying to do is create an object of a structure that is mapped to an address. Inside the struct, there is a dynamic array. How can I put a value in this case? I checked other answers on stack exchange but I can't find anything that works for my case. Help please.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 

contract Register{
    
    //state variables - stored permanently in contract storage 
    
    // goverment entity - municipality 
    address public govermentEntity; 
    
  
    //seller - sorting facility 
    struct Seller {
        address sellerAddress; 
        string sellerLocation;
        address [] sortingMachineAddress; // dynamic array 
        bool isExist;
    }
    

    
    //constructor - initilize state variables
    constructor() public{
     govermentEntity = msg.sender; 
    }
    
    // Mappings 
  
    mapping (address => Seller) registeredSellers; 
    
    modifier onlyGovermentEntity{
        require(msg.sender == govermentEntity, "Entity not authorized to register stakeholders.");
        _;
    }
    
    // register seller if it doesn't exist 
    function registerSeller (address addr, string memory sellerLocation, address sortingMachineAddress) public onlyGovermentEntity {
        require(registeredSellers[addr].isExist == false , "Seller is registered already."); 
        
        registeredSellers[addr] = Seller(addr, sellerLocation, sortingMachineAddress, true);  // WHAT IS A SORTING MACHINE ADDRESS AND HOW TO SAVE IT DYNAMICALLY???
    }
    
   
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
registeredSellers[addr] = Seller(addr, sellerLocation, sortingMachineAddress, true);
```

To this:

```
registeredSellers[addr].sellerAddress = addr;
registeredSellers[addr].sellerLocation = sellerLocation;
registeredSellers[addr].sortingMachineAddress.push(sortingMachineAddress);
registeredSellers[addr].isExist = true;
```

BTW, the `sellerAddress` field seems redundant, as it essentially maps a key to itself.

---

I would actually go one step further and change the function prototype from this:

```
function registerSeller(
    address addr,
    string memory sellerLocation,
    address sortingMachineAddress
)
```

To this:

```
function registerSeller(
    address addr,
    string memory sellerLocation,
    address[] memory sortingMachineAddress
)
```

And then do this:

```
registeredSellers[addr].sellerAddress = addr;
registeredSellers[addr].sellerLocation = sellerLocation;
registeredSellers[addr].isExist = true;
for (uint256 i = 0; i < sortingMachineAddress.length; i++)
    registeredSellers[addr].sortingMachineAddress.push(sortingMachineAddress[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm testing it out now but I don't know how to pass an array of addresses in remix IDE. Is it something like ["0x12....", "0x34..."]?

Comment: @Iman: I believe so.